# Is there a way to pass the accessKeyId and the secretKey to the aws-sdk v3 as a String?

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

I'm looking to call EC2 with a provided AWSkeyId and secret (stored, encrypted in DB)
I cannot find a way to pass them as a string.

I'm trying to use the `@aws-sdk/credential-providers` package.

But looking at this: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/blob/main/packages/credential-provider-node/src/defaultProvider.ts there is no way to use the `defaultProvider`.

Is there any other way to do that? appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well apparently there is no need to use the defaultProvider, as you can pass the credentials in any of was clients this way :

```
        const credentials = {
            accessKeyId: this.awsAccessKey,
            secretAccessKey: this.awsAccessSecret
        };

        this.ec2 = new EC2Client({ region: this.region, credentials });
```